# C# Is it possible to convert DateTime format to integer or float?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm having some trouble here.
Did some research on Google but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.
I'm trying to ask for two inputs (datetimes) in hh:mm format, subtract one for the other then return the result of that value in minutes.
The problem is that I want to return that value as an integer and I can't seem to find the right way to do it.
In C/C++ I wouldn't have this kind of issues...
Anyways, here's a snippet of what I'm talking about.

```
private int DuraçaoTreino(DateTime dtInicioTreino, DateTime dtFimTreino, int dtDuraçao)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Introduza a hora de inicio (hh:mm): ");
    dtInicioTreino = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.Read());
    Console.WriteLine("Introduza a hora de fim (hh:mm): ");
    dtFimTreino = Convert.ToDateTime(Console.Read());
    dtDuraçao = (dtFimTreino - dtInicioTreino); // duração da sessão de treino
    dtDuraçao = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.Read());
    return dtDuraçao;                  
}
```

And that's pretty much it... I'm new to C# so if you see anything wrong please be kind.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're talking about is a `TimeSpan`:

```
DateTime dtBegin   = new DateTime(2011,5,1,22,0,0) ; // 10pm 1 May 2011
DateTime dtEnd     = new DateTime(2011,5,1,23,0,0) ; // 11pm 1 May 2011
TimeSpan tmElapsed = dtEnd - dtBegin ;               // tmElapsed is a TimeSpan with a value of 60 minutes
```

To return the minutes, do something like:

```
int elapsedTimeInMinutes = (int) Math.Round( tmElapsed.TotalMinutes , 0 ,MidpointRounding.ToEven ) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var timeInMinutes = new DateTime(2011, 12, 25).Subtract(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1)).TotalMinutes;
```

Instead of creating the DateTime objects using the constructor I used, you can use DateTime.Parse, or better still DateTime.ParseExact to convert the strings to date times. (I know I am only using date parts here but you choose only to use time parts if you wish)

Answer (score 0):

Convert DateTime objects to TimeSpan's, substract and call TimeSpan.TotalMinutes (or smth like that - dont' have VS at hand):

```
DateTime dt1, dt2;
```

// Assign some dates, then:

```
TimeSpan ts = dt2 - dt1;
```

double minutes = ts.TotalMinutes;

Comment: it would be `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`

Comment: It can be either - TotalMinutes returns double, where Minutes returns rounded int